# Sorting a table on javascript and reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need to make a table that sorts itself dependind on the header of the section selected, im using react and javascript. i already make it sorteable but when i clicked on the name again it doesnt sort again

this is my code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      Route,
      Link,
      Redirect,
      NavLink
    } from 'react-router-dom'
    import UbicationForm from './UbicationForm';    
    let order = 'desc';
    class TableCiudades extends Component {
        state = {
            sort:null
        }
        sortCiudades = (ciudades,label) => {
            let newCiudades = [...ciudades]
            newCiudades.sort(function(a, b) {
                if (a[label] > b[label]) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (a[label] < b[label]) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
            return newCiudades
        }
        addSort = (label) => {
            let {sort=null} = this.state
                    this.setState({
                        sort:label
                    })

                }

    render(){
        let { sort=null } = this.state
        let { ciudades=[] } = this.props
        if (sort !== null) {
            ciudades = this.sortCiudades(ciudades,sort)
        }
        var {toCity} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th><a onClick={()=>this.addSort('name')}>name</a></th>
                        <th><a onClick={()=>this.addSort('stateName')}>stateName</a></th> 
                        <th><a onClick={()=>this.addSort('countryName')}>countryName</a></th>
                        <th><a onClick={()=>this.addSort('segmentsCount')}>Segments Count</a></th> 
                        <th><a onClick={()=>this.addSort('venuesCount')}>Venues Count</a></th>
                        <th></th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>


     <tbody>
                    {ciudades.map((ciudad, i) => 
                            (<tr key={'ciudad-'+i}>
                                <td>{ciudad.name}</td>
                                <td>{ciudad.stateName}</td> 
                                <td>{ciudad.countryName}</td>
                                <td>{ciudad.segmentsCount}</td> 
                                <td>{ciudad.venuesCount}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>toCity(ciudad._id,'segments')}>Segments</button>
                                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={()=>toCity(ciudad._id,'venues')}>Venues</button>
                                </td>
                              </tr>   
                              ) 
                        )}

                  </tbody>
                </table></div>
            )
    }
}

    export default class CiudadesSegVen extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            var last = this.props.match.params.last ? 

        this.props.match.params.last : ''
                this.state = {
                    ciudades:[],
              last:last
        };
    }
    lastChanged = (event) => {
        this.setState({last: event.target.value});
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: "/prueba

s/"+event.target.value,
            });
        }
        ciudadesSegVen = (event) => {
            let params = this.props.match.params;
            let query = params.query?params.query:0;
            let country = params.country?params.country:0;
            let state = params.state?params.state:0;
            let city = params.city?params.city:0;
            fetch("/ciudadesSegVen",{
                    credentials: "same-origin",
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                    body:JSON.stringify({
                        country:country,
                        state:state,
                        city:city,
                    })
                })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(
                    (result) => {
                        console.log(result)
                        this.setState({
                            ciudades:result
                        })
                    },
                    (error) => {
                      this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                      });
                    }
                );
        }
        toCity = (cityID,tipo) => {
            let params = this.props.match.params;
            let query = this.props.query?this.props.query:params.query?params.query:0;
            let country = params.country?params.country:0;
            let state = params.state?params.state:0;
            this.props.history.push(`/cities/${tipo}/${country}/${state}/${cityID}`,{show:1})
        }
        render() {
            return (
              <div className="row">
                    <nav className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-light sidebar">

                        <UbicationForm {...this.props} collection="cities" query='segven' />
                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={this.ciudadesSegVen} >Search</button>
                      </nav>
                  <main role="main" className="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3">
                    <h1>Count</h1>
                    <TableCiudades ciudades={this.state.ciudades} toCity={this.toCity}/>
                  </main>
              </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

i know i could use react-datadabke or a library that can make this things by itself, but i need to make it this way, thanks for your help in advance =)

Comment: If you make an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: The problem is probably with your 'key'. First test is to try randomizing that number instead of using `i`... try putting in `key={'ciudad-'+Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)}`

Comment: (but be sure you don't leave it that way if it fixes it)